# Silverlight 4, subclassing WebClient

Tags: silverlight, cookies, silverlight-4.0, webclient

Following an advice, I saw at several web pages (for example [Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/c-using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class)), I subclassed WebClient class to use a cookie with it:

```
public class MyWebClient : System.Net.WebClient
{

}
```

Now, when I initialize MyWebClient:

```
MyWebClient wc = new MyWebClient();
```

it throws TypeLoadException. My OS is Windows 7 (japanese), so error message is not in english; I see it is related to security rules. What might be the problem?

Comment: instead of inheritance you should use composition

Answer (score 2):

WebClient's constructor is marked with the `SecuritySafeCritical` attribute.  And it looks like that is what is causing the security exception.  I tried applying that same attribute to `MyWebClient`'s constructor but that didn't work.  From what I've read, this kind of thing just isn't allowed in Silverlight.  For example, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627417/security-rules-for-subclassing-transparent-type-with-safe-critical-constructor-in).

For reference, the exact exception message is:

> System.TypeLoadException
>
> Inheritance security rules violated while
> overriding member: 'MyWebClient..ctor()'. Security accessibility of
> the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the
> method being overriden.

I wish there was a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a default constructor with the SecuritySafeCritical attribute. Had this problem today and that was the solution.

```
public class MyWebClient : System.Net.WebClient
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public MyWebClient() : base() {}
}
```